# How to handle Async http call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I am creating some employee app which basically fetch the data from `http call(json)` and display it using angularjs. 
The problem is before getting the response from `http` call my view got executed, so nothing displayed in my output page. I know there should be some logic to handle the async call but i am not aware of that, so could someone please help me?

**Home.html**

```
<html ng-app="employeeApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Employee Example</title>
<script
    src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var employeeApp = angular.module('employeeApp', []);
    employeeApp.controller('EmployeeCtrl', ['$http','$scope',
            function(http, scope) {
                http.get('http://localhost:9999/employee/7').success(
                        function(data) {
                            scope.employees = data;
                        });
            } ]);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="EmployeeCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>AGE</th>
            <th>LOCATION</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.location}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

**Actual output:**

[image]

**My Expected output:**
[image]

**Note:**
If i load from json file or run from web browser i got the expected output but its not working in Angular script.

```
http://localhost:9999/employee/7
{"id":7,"age":65,"name":"test","location":"singapore"}
```

Comment: are you sure there are no CORS issues in your browser? That happens if the api server is on a different host or port than your application server

Comment: also chain a ```.catch(function(error){console.log('error', error);})``` to your http promise to make sure to catch any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't see any data because 'employees' is not array (i.e. your endpoint returns just one object).

Either return array of object(s) from your endpoint or if you always get only one object then remove ng-repeat and replace 'employee' with 'employees' in your binding.

Note: When you use object in ng-repeat then it will iterate properties in the object.

Answer (score 3):

You are expecting ng-repeat to get a "list" of objects. What you are getting instead is a single object which ng-repeat is likely iterating though. Each property however does not have the expected properties of id, name etc.

What you should be returning instead in your ajax response should more like this:

```
[
  {"id":7,"age":65,"name":"test","location":"singapore"},
  {"id":7,"age":65,"name":"test","location":"singapore"},
  {"id":7,"age":65,"name":"test","location":"singapore"},
  {"id":7,"age":65,"name":"test","location":"singapore"}
]
```

Or, for a single item it would be:

```
[
  {"id":7,"age":65,"name":"test","location":"singapore"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both Mani and you answered correctly but first he responded to this question so i am accepting his answer and upvote for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome Developer Tool (press F12 on Chrome) to debug the script. 
Watch "Network" tab for response data from server.

One other way I usually use to check bug like this is to print directly the varaiable to the template like this:

```
<body ng-controller="EmployeeCtrl">
{{employees}}
</body>
```

Sometime this helps me find out what happned to my data. Just remember to clear that after you solve the problem :)